# Carregando reportviewer através de um objeto

Tags: c#, relatório, reportviewer

Estou utilizando o Report Viewer para fazer alguns relatórios, mas não estou conseguindo acessar alguns dados do meu objeto. 
ao invés de fazer conexão direta com o banco eu passo um DataTable como referencia, e já no ReportViewer eu adiciono um DataSet Object.
Essa é a seguinte estrutura utilizada:

```
class Produto{
    public int Codigo{get;set}
    public string NomeProduto {get;set;}
    public Categoria Cat {get;set;}
}

class Categoria{
    public int Codigo{get;set}
    public string NomeCategoria{get;set;}
}
```

No ReportViewer eu tenho acesso normal ao Código e NomeProduto porém não consigo acessar os itens do meu objeto Categoria ... Eu utilizo a expressão `=Fields!Codigo.Value` para Recuperar o código do Produto e no Fields da Expression aparece uma opção com a Categoria `First(Fields!Categoria.Value, "Data")` porém mesmo que eu coloque isso ele não carrega nada, queria saber como é possivel carrega o nome da Categoria, por exemplo `First(Fields!(Categoria.NomeCategoria).Value, "Data")`

Answer (score 1):

É só você associar o DataSet ao seu Table no Report (Os atributos tem de ter o mesmo nome), e passar a lista `modelList` para o `DataSource`:

```
LocalReport relatorio = new LocalReport();
relatorio.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DSTituloProjetado", modelList));
```